# Can a page that ALWAYS redirects get a PostBack?

Tags: asp.net, postback

I've inherited an old Asp.Net website (I've had limited exposure to Asp & Web stuff).

One of the pages takes values from a query string, does some giggery pokery with them **and then re-directs to another page**.

The existing code has some Session State logic in there to remember the giggery pokery in case of PostBacks, but I'm wondering if it's necessary.

Can a page that *always* redirects be posted back?

Apologies if this is [a dumb question](http://marinelife.about.com/b/2009/05/16/are-whales-fish.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it **always** redirects then no it cannot receive a postback, (from itself)

there are details of the page lifecycle here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

Comment: Let's assume PageA.aspx always redirects. What if PageB.aspx has <asp:Button ... PostBackUrl="PageA.aspx"/>?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and for the link. The link is informative, but I couldn't identify a portion that supports your answer. Is it supposed to support it? or is it just extra information? Thanks again, either way.

Comment: @rciq: Good point, in this instance I can assure you that won't happen, not from within the site anyway.

Comment: @Binary Worrier, if you can **GUARANTEE** that there are no postbacks from within your site then the code is redundant. I would add a logging function to this postback code and run it for a while to see if it ever hits. (get it to email you too when it recieves a postback) if after a few weeks of operation you see no email and log is empty then delete the code :-)

Comment: I would if I could. However this is (a very small) part of a product we ship, also, the giggery pokery all happens in memory and it isn't the end of the world if it has to happen on each post, so I'm very much leaning toward taking the fecking thing out. Ta.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it could postback, but how is your setup?  Without seeing, it's hard to give you any definitive answer.

Thanks.

Comment: "But how is your setup". Sure, what do you need to see?

Comment: What is making it redirect, are you calling Response.Redirect, or are you manipulating the form element, or are you using JavaScript, or are you using PostBackUrl property on the button?

Comment: The page is hit by an external request (not us, a clients application opens the URL), we never postback to the page in anyway.